# Add Jquery datepicker in one of the columns using angular JS datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I want to show some data in `datatable` and in of those columns I want to show a textbox with `Datepicker`. Below is my angular js code in this I want to add my `datepicker`.

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['datatables']);
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder',
    function ($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
        $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("OBJECTID", "ID"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("SERVICE_CODE", "Service Code"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("COND1", "Condition 1"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("COND2", "Condition 2"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("COND3", "Condition 3"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("SERVICE_TYPE", "Service type"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("REMARK", "Remark"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("DATE", "date")
        ]
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
            url: "/home/getdata",
            type: "POST"
        })
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        .withDisplayLength(10);
    }])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

So, how could I will be able to add it ?? Please let me know as I am totally new to Angular JS

**update**

[image: Sample Data Img]

Comment: You need to add sample data to make snippet work and add expected output.

Comment: @Justcode: I just want to add the datepicker in my above screenshot images in of the columns, so how should I do it ?

Comment: Which datepicker would you like to integrate into your app? Is it JQuery-UI one or Bootstrap or something else?

Comment: @arcquim : I want jquery ui datepicker. Please suggest if u can help in this

Answer (score 1):

Instead of jquery datepicker you can go for the angular ui datepicker which is highly customizable and supported for angular js version.
Below is the link for angualr ui datepicker 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker
You can read and do and pass your data to date object for angular datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Angular Datatables the "angular way" to be able to include custom directive in your table cells. Take a look at this [plunk](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/ZQa1ZeLZtWkAfpDZk6Lr) with working Angular Datatables using the "angular way" with a custom jQuery UI datepicker directive. From there, you can control where the datepicker will appear based on a condition using `ng-if` for example.

Link for Angular Datatables "The Angular Way": https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/angularWay

Comment: where should I add my `data.json` data in my project ?? rest I have done

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in JQuery datatables, but made some kind of research. It's not a complete showcase, but some kind of first-step-tutorial.

The first thing you need is to define a custom renderer for your `Date` column. You can do it as follows:

```
$scope.dtColumns = [
    ...,
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("DATE", "date").renderWith(renderTextBox);
]
...
function renderTextBox(data, type, full, meta) {
    return `<input value="${data}" ng-model="date${meta.row}" customdatepicker>`;
}
```

Here `renderWith` is an api method of `DTColumnBuilder`, that accepts four parameters. The most important of them are `data` and `meta` - your current value and metainfo of a cell (it contains `row` and `column` number properties - cell coordinates). `ng-model` helps you to bind input value to your `homeCtrl` `scope` object. I believe you need the datepicker in each row, that's why I bind its value to an attribute dependent on a row index. It means at anytime you can get your selected date as a value of `date0` key in `homeCtrl` `scope` (for the row with `0` index). Furthermore, `customdatepicker` is explained below.

As we're trying to bind datepicker into an `input` element, we're modifying DOM. In AngularJS it's the best practice to modify DOM in directives. That's why we define our custom directive. Let's name it `customdatepicker`:

```
angular.module('MyApp').directive('customdatepicker', CustomDatepicker);
function CustomDatepicker() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(element).datepicker({
                defaultDate: attrs.value,
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope[attrs.ngModel] = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Let me explain this. We're using directive to modify specific element, that's why we're restricting this to be attribute-only (`restrict: 'A'`). It requires from an element to have an `ng-model` defined to modify it - and `require: 'ngModel` is used here. Finally, `link` function is executed when `input` element is compiled by AngularJS. It takes `scope` against which it's compiled, `element` to which it's bound, parsed `attrs` of the element, and `ngModelCtrl`. We're using simple JQuery-UI `datepicker` function here. After a date is selected, we modify `scope`, and manually call `scope.$apply()` to notify `homeCtrl` about `scope` change.

Finally, your code may look like this:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['datatables']);
app.directive('customdatepicker', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          $(element).datepicker({
              defaultDate: attrs.value,
              onSelect: function (date) {
                  scope[attrs.ngModel] = date;
                  scope.$apply();
              }
          });
      }
    };
});
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder',
    function ($scope, $http, $compile, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
        $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("OBJECTID", "ID"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("SERVICE_CODE", "Service Code"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("COND1", "Condition 1"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("COND2", "Condition 2"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("COND3", "Condition 3"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("SERVICE_TYPE", "Service type"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("REMARK", "Remark"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("DATE", "date").renderWith(renderTextBox)
        ]
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
            url: "/home/getdata",
            type: "POST"
        })
        .withOption('createdRow', function(row) {
            $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
        })
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        .withDisplayLength(10);

        function renderTextBox(data, type, full, meta) {
            return `<input value="${data}" ng-model="date${meta.row}" customdatepicker>`;
        }
    }]
);
```

Please note that we use `createdRow` option and provide a callback here that is fired when a row is created. Here we manually angularjs-compile row element against `homeCtrl` `$scope` - that makes binding working.

And do not forget to include JQuery-UI CDN into your project after your JQuery import.